# Memory allocation in MySQL datatypes?

Tags: mysql, sql, memory, sqldatatypes

I am new to the MySQL. I have little bit confusion about memory allocation for datatypes. If I initialize type as bigint it will take 8 bytes of memory. If I initialize bigint(10) then would it take 80 bytes or same 8 bytes with limitations. what is use of initializing 10 over the datatype? And also I have bit confused in varchar as well. what would be the memory size of varchar(10) and varchar(100)? will it differ in memory size? Am using InnoDB engine.

Comment: maybe useful? [Mysql: 11.8 Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: @Ryan you mean bigint(10) and bigint(100) allocate same size of memory. No difference in that, isn't it?

Comment: Correct: a `bigint` will **always** use 8 bytes in the database. The `(10)` means that the default width when displayed will be 10 characters. The link I provided earlier explains how to work out how much space will be occupied by the different data types.

Answer (score 3):

Numeric datatypes take a fixed amount of space when not `NULL`.

`VARCHAR(n)` takes 1 or 2 bytes for the length, plus room for however many characters you have -- up to `n`.  Note:  I say "characters", not "bytes".  For `ascii` and `latin1`, one character occupies one byte.  But for `utf8`, one character takes *up to* 3 bytes.

`VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8` will take between 1 byte (for the empty string) and 32 bytes.
`VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8` will take between 2 bytes and 302 bytes.
`VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8` will take between 2 bytes and 767 bytes.

`CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8` will always take 30 bytes.  Hence, `VARCHAR` is usually a better choice than `CHAR`.

`NULL` is special-cased and takes virtually no space.  A related comment:  Should I use `... NOT NULL` and use `''`?  or use `NULLs`?  The space difference is not as important as the semantics.  Use `NULL` when suitable for your app.